# Getting Facebook "publish_actions" permission

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish-actions

I have been working on a mobile application. It has some locked features. To open them, user should share the web page of my application on Facebook. I'm using [share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) to make it. I'm publishing the Facebook post's details on my web page with using graph api and postId which comes from onsuccess.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/troubleshooting#faq_288512448203790 in this page Facebook says I need "publish_actions" permission to get the postId while I'm using share dialog.

But, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-publish_actions in this page it says "if you are using share dialog do not request this permission."

And if I use custom dialog, facebook does not accept to share my web page.

So, my question is; What should I do to get "publish_actions" permission ?

Comment: You are __not allowed__ to gate content behind a forced share. Suggest you go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) first of all.

Answer (score 0):

you can still get the approval, but explaining it to facebook review team and user must be aware of the hidden posting and one more thing giving incentives or forcing users to share is not permitted by facebook policies.

Comment: I made custom share dialog instead of share dialog. It worked !